# Wrong way the page starts and undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, calendar

So I got this

> Notice: Undefined variable: date_clicked

I know from where it comes, but I don't know how to solve it. And also, I'm trying to make the calendar start with the current day in the url. Without having me to click on that day.
Any help with my problems?

my database

```
  CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `users` (
                  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

calendar.php

```
     <?php
session_start();
include "connection.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location="calendar1.php?";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>

<style type="text/css">
<?php include 'style.css'; ?>
</style>

<?php
$month_date = date('m');
$year_date = date('Y');
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bucharest");

if(isset($_GET['month'])) {
    $month = $_GET['month'];
} else {
    $month = $month_date;
}

if(isset($_GET['year'])) {
    $year = $_GET['year'];
} else {
    $year = $year_date;
}

if(isset($_GET['day'])) {
    $day_clicked = $_GET['day'];
    $date_clicked = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day_clicked;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($_FILES["f1"]["error"] == 0) {
        $tm=md5(time());
        $fnm=$_FILES["f1"]["name"];
        $destination="./images/".$tm.$fnm;
        $destination1="images/".$tm.$fnm;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["f1"]["tmp_name"],$destination);

        mysqli_query($link,"insert into events (`type`, `name`, `date`, `created`, `image`)
                                   values ('$_POST[radio]','$_POST[name]','$date_clicked','$created','$destination1')");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($link,"insert into events  (`type`, `name`, `date`, `created`)
                                   values ('$_POST[radio]','$_POST[name]','$date_clicked','$created')");
    }

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}

$today = 0;
if($month == $month_date && $year == $year_date) {
    $today = date('d');
}

$data = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
$last_day = date("t",$data);
$this_month = getdate ($data);
$start_day = $this_month['wday']-1;

if($start_day < 0 ) {
    $start_day = 6;
}

$prev = $next = 'calendar1.php?month=';
$prev .= ($month == 1 ? '12&amp;year='.($year-1) : ($month-1).'&amp;year='.$year);
$next .= ($month == 12 ? '1&amp;year='.($year+1) : ($month+1).'&amp;year='.$year);

echo '
    <div class="calendar">
        <div class="direction">

            <a href="',$prev,'" class="previous">Previous</a>
            <a href="',$next,'" class="next">Next</a>

        </div>

  <table>
        <caption>',date("F",$data),' ',$year,'</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Mo</th>
                <th scope="col">Tu</th>
                <th scope="col">We</th>
                <th scope="col">Th</th>
                <th scope="col">Fr</th>
                <th scope="col">Sa</th>
                <th scope="col">Su</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>';

$i=0;
while ($i < $start_day) {
    echo '<td></td>';
    $i++;
}

$month_events = mysqli_query($link,"select date from events where date LIKE '".$year . '-' . $month."%' GROUP BY date");

while($month_event = mysqli_fetch_assoc($month_events)) {
    $has_event[$month_event['date']] = true;
}

$day = 1;
while($day <= $last_day) {
    if (($i % 7) == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    ?>

<?php if(strlen($day) == 1) {
    $comp_date = $year . '-' . $month . '-0' . $day;
} else {
    $comp_date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
}
?>

    <td <?php   if($day == $today){
                    echo "class='today'";
                } elseif(isset($has_event[$comp_date])) {
                    echo "class='evenbox'";
                }
        ?>>

       <?php echo "<a  class='onclick' href='?month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."'>".$day."</a>"; ?>
    </td>

    <?php
    if ((++$i % 7) == 0) { ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    $day++;

}

if (($i % 7) > 0) {
    while ($i++ % 7 > 0) { ?>
        <td></td>
        <?php
    } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>


</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <?php
    $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from events where date='$date_clicked'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    { ?>
        Today: <?php echo $row["name"]; ?><br />
        Event type: <?php echo $row["type"]; ?><br />
        Added: <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row["created"])); ?><br />
        <?php if($row["image"] != '') {
            echo '<img src="'.$row["image"].'" style="max-width:100px;height:auto;" />';
        } ?>
        <hr />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>

    <br/>


    <button id="button" onclick="javascript:showhide();" >Add events </button>
    <div id="events" class="events">

    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <table>
            <tr>
       <td> <label for="name">Insert data</label>
        <br/>
            <textarea name="name" id="name" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Add details about event here" required=""></textarea>
           <br class="clear" />
       </td>
            </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>
        <label for="type">Type</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="0" id="type" required="" />0
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" id="type" required="" />1
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="type" required=""/>2
        <br class="clear" />
            </td>
       </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="type">Insert image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="f1" /></td>

            </tr>


            <tr>
             <td>
                 <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="click" value="Submit">

              </td>
         </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide()
    {
        var div = document.getElementById("events");
        if (div.style.display === "block") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

login.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include "connection.php";
    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        <?php include 'loginform.css'; ?>
    </style>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>


    <body class="login">
    <div class="login_wrapper">

        <section class="login_content">
            <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required=""/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <input class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Login">

                </div>


                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <br/>


    </div>
    </form>
    </section>



    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
    {
        $reg = mysqli_query($link, "select * from users where username='$_POST[username]'");
        if($count = mysqli_num_rows($reg)){
        $security_hash = '&*^HJVkhjJYHGF7896(*jkbad78JHB#)R(JV';
        $password = hash('md5', $_POST['password'].$security_hash);
            ?>
        <?php
        $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location="calendar1.php?";
        </script>

        <?php

        }
        else
        {
      ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
            <strong style="color:white">Incorect</strong> username or password
        </div>
            <?php

        }
    }

    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

---

connection.h

```
    <?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"calendar");

if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}
?>
```

---

loginform.css

```
.login {
    background: white;
}
.login_wrapper {
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    max-width: 350px;
    position: relative
}

.clearfix:after,
form:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden
}

.login_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    min-width: 280px
}

.login_content form {
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative
}

.form-control{
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}

.login_content .btn-default:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}

.login_content a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.login_content h1 {
    font: normal 25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0 30px
}

.login_content h1:after {
    background: #7e7e7e;
    background: linear-gradient(left, #7e7e7e 0%, #fff 100%);
    right: 0
}
.login_content h1:before {
    background: #7e7e7e;
    background: linear-gradient(right, #7e7e7e 0%, #fff 100%);
    left: 0
}

.login_content h1:before,
.login_content h1:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 27%
}
```

---

style.css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    padding-left:0;

}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.calendar {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    color: #000000;
    background: white;
    width:800px;
    float:left;
}

.calendar .direction a {
    color: #010101;
}


.calendar .direction .previous {
    padding:0.25em;
    float: left;

}

.calendar .direction .next {
    padding:0.25em;
    float: right;

}

.calendar table {
    width:80%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    color: #000000;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

.calendar caption {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0.25em;
    background: #AAA;
    text-align: center;
}

.calendar th,
.calendar td {
    padding:0.1em;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    height:100px;
}

.calendar .today {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: orange;
}

.calendar th:nth-of-type(6),
.calendar td:nth-of-type(6) {
    color: red;
}
.calendar th:nth-of-type(7),
.calendar td:nth-of-type(7) {
    color: red;
}

#events {
    width:600px;
    float:right;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;

}


.calendar .evenbox{
    background: linear-gradient(225deg, red, red 10px, transparent 10px, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Dont post entire code, provide a minimal piece of code that is enough to solve the issue

Comment: Sorry. I posted twice the same code

Comment: I want to set the url to the current  day when i load the page for the first time, without clicking that date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below

```
if(isset($_GET['day'])) {
    $day_clicked = $_GET['day'];
    $date_clicked = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day_clicked;
}
```

in your current code add another test to see if $date_clicked has been set and, if it hasn't been, go ahead and set it.

```
if (!isset($date_clicked)) {
     $date_clicked = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . date('d');
}
```